# Metro Tabular data

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

I'm working on an application that displays large amounts of data at a time.  It could be as much as 100k sortable records.  There are about 6 or 7 fields to display.  Traditionally, I'd use a gridview to display the data.

Gridviews are currently frowned upon in Metro style applications.  What's the alternative to using faux tables in metro?  Virtualized templated "boxes" with pieces the 6 or 7 tidbits of data in them?  It seems to me that would be a terrible user experience.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- you can still create a data grid-esque like experience using the list layout for a list view.
- tha giant grid view reall *is* often a horrible experience.

If you have lots of data for people to review, with occasional editing, I would use a flyOut that shows up on clicking/tapping.

If its tabular data, and the best editing experience is something ala excel, then you can build it - it just doesn't come outta the box like that.

For the UX aspects of this, try us.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, GridViews are frowned on because of the possibility of someone trying to use this on a touch device.

Are you able to categorize your data.  If you have a look at some of the sample apps on the App Store, they do display large quantities of data, but you initially get some categories.    This also helps with the responsiveness, as loading that much data into memory at one time is going to take some time.